# Example H-unital algebra which is not unital

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, hochschild-homology

What is an example of an algebra which is H-unital (that is its Bar complex is acyclic) and yet it is not unital?

Comment: Anything with local units (this example is in Loday's book). There is also a version of H-unitality for Banach algebras, in which case having a bounded approximate identity guarantees H-unitality

Comment: Cool I'll check that out, Thanks Yemon :D